# Handle ambiguous struct declarations while debugging C code

Tags: c, debugging, pdb-files, one-definition-rule, proj

I'm currently debugging through code for a certain coordinate projection algorithm in osgeo/proj.4, to compare it with another implementation where I suspect the presence of a bug.

proj.4 contains multiple different declarations for a certain struct with the same name, each one of those in a separate .c-file:

```
struct pj_opaque {
    double phic0;
    double cosc0, sinc0;
    double R2;
    void *en;
};

struct pj_opaque {
    double K, c, hlf_e, kR, cosp0, sinp0;
};
```

(and many more).
The correct struct declaration I'm interested in:

```
struct pj_opaque {
    double  A, B, E, AB, ArB, BrA, rB, singam, cosgam, sinrot, cosrot;
    double  v_pole_n, v_pole_s, u_0;
    int no_rot;
};
```

This seems to cause problems in the debugger. At runtime, I'm not able to view all values of a struct I'm interested in, because the debugger uses an incompatible declaration for the type, which doesn't have the members I want to look at.

Here is an example:
Q is of type pj_opaque*, I want to look at the member u_0. In the watch, struct Q does not even have a member u_0. Accessing it directly via Q->u_0 gives an error. (class"XYZ" has no member "UVW")

[image: Visual Studio debugger/watch uses wrong struct declaration]

Is there a general way to deal with this kind of ambiguity while debugging, like a compiler switch, which makes those ambiguous names unique?

For the record: proj.4 is built with vcpkg on Windows, debugger is Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: the general way would be to not have such ambiguous names... :F

Comment: And definitely don't re-use the same name for different datatypes

Comment: @Antti Haapala: yes, but I'm not the author of proj.4, so changing their code isn't really a choice.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that from the caller, the struct declaration is opaque so you won't be able to see it, regardless of if there's one or several struct definitions elsewhere.

Comment: @Lundin Can you please explain what you mean a little bit more detailed? The code I'm debugging is not in caller-scope, it is within proj.4. I have the sources and debugging symbols for proj.4 available.

Comment: I'd define a new type `struct pj_opaque_for_debug { ...everything I want to see...};` and cast the pointer to this type inside the debugger (if possible with your debugger). For example, in `gdb` I'd type `print * (struct pj_opaque_for_debug*) p` instead of `print *p`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that from the caller, the struct declaration is opaque so you won't be able to see it, regardless of if there's one or several struct definitions elsewhere. Meaning that the caller just has an incomplete declaration such as `typedef struct pj_opaque pj_opaque` somewhere. This means that the caller can't know the contents of that struct, it is a way to do OO and private encapsulation in C.

The sensible thing to do would be something like:

```
// top of caller .c file
#ifdef DEBUG_RELEASE
struct pj_opaque { /* definition here */ };
#endif
```

This allows the compiler of the caller .c file to know what the structure contains, pass this on to the object file, which in turn can get passed on to the debugger file format. This is a bit dirty though, since it exposes the code to the caller, if only in debug mode. A prettier alternative would be to create a header file like "pj_opaque_debug.h" where you put the above compiler switch code.

Comment: Don't know if this helps. Struct declaration is already done in the .implementation-.c-file im debugging.

Comment: @MatthiasS. Hmm okay then the problem might be something else entirely, like some naming conflict. Behind the lines somewhere, there should be "name mangling" if `pj_opaque` exists in different places with different definitions.

Comment: I looked at the pdb with cvdump, and indeed, there is a warning it's something wrong with the struct pj_opaque ("WARNUNG: UDT mismatch for pj_opaque", unique name is the same for each struct). My guess is, pdb file can't handle the different variants of the struct with the same name, so one of the over 60 different declarations was randomly chosen and written to the pdb file.